# Erased my database

Tags: management

I've just recently bought a host with a domain and as I was following a tutorial on youtube for installing wordpress I accidentally erased my primary database. So now my site doesn't even have the default inserts it had from the beginning. When I write the website adress in the web browser it says: "Error establishing a database connection." Then in cpanel as I enter Domain my webaddress is there but when I click on manage domain it says: "No configuration options currently exist for the “here it says my domainname” domain."

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Restore from backups.

Learn never to use production database/server for learning purposes.